# Why doesn't my procedure show data that falls between specified date ranges?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this stored procedure, it takes dates to show data between date range but it always show all data. It should show the data that falls between specified date ranges but it doesn't. Why ?

```
Select CaseLetters.pk_CaseLetters_CaseLetterID, CaseLetters.CaseLetterNo, CaseLetters.CaseLetterComments, Convert(varchar, CaseLetters.CaseLetterDate, 106) as CaseLetterDate,
       CaseLetters.CaseLetterEntryDateTime, CaseLetters.fk_Cases_CaseLetters_CaseID, Cases.CaseNo, CaseLetters.fk_WebUsers_CaseLetters_UserID, CaseLetterDate, ConcernedOffices.ConcernedOfficeName,
       Districts.DistrictName, CaseLetters.LetterFrom, CaseLetters.LetterTo, CaseLetters.LetterBody
    From CaseLetters
        Inner Join Cases ON Cases.pk_Cases_CaseID = CaseLetters.fk_Cases_CaseLetters_CaseID
        Inner Join ConcernedOffices ON ConcernedOffices.pk_ConcernedOffices_ID = CaseLetters.fk_ConcernedOffices_CaseHearings_ConcernedOfficeID
        Inner Join Districts ON Districts.pk_Districts_DistrictID = ConcernedOffices.fk_Districts_ConcernedOffices_DistrictID
        Inner Join Web_Users ON Web_Users.UserID = CaseLetters.fk_WebUsers_CaseLetters_UserID
    Where Cases.CaseNo like '%'+ @CaseNo +'%' AND
          (CaseLetters.CaseLetterDate >= @DateFrom AND
          CaseLetters.CaseLetterDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @DateTo))
```

while `DateFrom` and `DateTo` are of `Datetime` datatype.

Comment: Please verify date formats of variable DateFrom and DateTo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **BETWEEN** :

```
Select CaseLetters.pk_CaseLetters_CaseLetterID, CaseLetters.CaseLetterNo, CaseLetters.CaseLetterComments, Convert(varchar, CaseLetters.CaseLetterDate, 106) as CaseLetterDate,
       CaseLetters.CaseLetterEntryDateTime, CaseLetters.fk_Cases_CaseLetters_CaseID, Cases.CaseNo, CaseLetters.fk_WebUsers_CaseLetters_UserID, CaseLetterDate, ConcernedOffices.ConcernedOfficeName,
       Districts.DistrictName, CaseLetters.LetterFrom, CaseLetters.LetterTo, CaseLetters.LetterBody
    From CaseLetters
        Inner Join Cases ON Cases.pk_Cases_CaseID = CaseLetters.fk_Cases_CaseLetters_CaseID
        Inner Join ConcernedOffices ON ConcernedOffices.pk_ConcernedOffices_ID = CaseLetters.fk_ConcernedOffices_CaseHearings_ConcernedOfficeID
        Inner Join Districts ON Districts.pk_Districts_DistrictID = ConcernedOffices.fk_Districts_ConcernedOffices_DistrictID
        Inner Join Web_Users ON Web_Users.UserID = CaseLetters.fk_WebUsers_CaseLetters_UserID
    Where Cases.CaseNo like '%'+ @CaseNo +'%' AND
          (CaseLetters.CaseLetterDate BETWEEN @DateFrom AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, @DateTo))
```